# Finding the closest location out of 300 destinations from 1 random location using Swift

Tags: swift, api, location

I have a set of 1000 international airports from around the world and their GPS location. The user will enter a city and then I will get the GPS location for that city. There will be a departure city and an intl airport.

How would I be able to determine which international airport is closest to the departure city in Swift?

I'm assuming I use the location manager for iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the distance between this 300 location and user location and find the minimum distance from this distance.

i.e

```
 //User Location
    var userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 40.23432, longitude: -90.23423)

    //Airport locations
    var airportLocations = [CLLocation(latitude: 32.838383, longitude: -116.973915),
                            CLLocation(latitude: 38.033878, longitude: -121.960709),
                            CLLocation(latitude: 40.167206, longitude: -105.101929),
                            CLLocation(latitude: 47.530102, longitude: -122.032616),
                            CLLocation(latitude: 41.081757, longitude: -81.511452),
                            CLLocation(latitude: 41.584660, longitude: -87.500160)]

    //Return distance array according to user location from airport
    let distance = airportLocations.map { $0.distance(from: userLocation) / 1000 }

    print(distance)  //Distance in KM
   // [2519.6894818028723, 2739.3624011808256, 1264.4208604451956, 2659.4695966766976, 743.32894364251479, 274.85755129294074]

  // Find the minimum value is your nearest location from user location
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to implement this using your help. Much appreciated.